# Apache simple rewrite rule works nice when in httpd-vhosts.conf but not when in .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Apache 2.4, Windows 10

virtual host in httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost sporemvc:80>
    ServerAdmin jakub.sawczuk@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24vhosts/hosts/sporemvc"
    ServerName sporemvc
    ErrorLog "logs/sporemvc-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/sporemvc-access.log" common
    <Directory C:/Apache24vhosts/hosts/sporemvc>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php [L]
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works nice. And proves mod_rewrite is on.

When the whole Directory is not there:

```
<VirtualHost sporemvc:80>
    ServerAdmin jakub.sawczuk@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/Apache24vhosts/hosts/sporemvc"
    ServerName sporemvc
    ErrorLog "logs/sporemvc-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/sporemvc-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

and there is C:/Apache24vhosts/hosts/sporemvc/.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
```

The rewrite rule seem not to work at all - Apache says 404. What could be a problem? I made sure mod_rewrite is on and even that .htaccess is ANSI not UTF. In Apache's and in vhost's logs there is nothing more than 404s.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: You need to enable the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files. Take a look at their documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Apart from that - why would you want to use `.htaccess` style files, if you have acces to and control over the real http host configuration? Those files only create issues and slow down the server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. 

To answer your question on `.htaccess` - I have control over development web serwer, that's right. But I may have not in controlled environments. Also this setting in `conf` requires server restart which may be less of convenience in production.

Comment: Restarting an apache http server in a production environment is not an issue at all. That is what the `graceful` command is for. In contrary: fiddling with `.htaccess` style files in a production environment imposes a _far_ bigger risk: once saved, they are life and potentially break your whole server. End of the game. If however you use the host configuration as recommended by the apache foundation, then you can silently test changes for syntactical correctness _before_ they go live. Just take a look at the control options the http server offers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am dumb.

It was `AllowOverride` None to be changed to `AllowOverride All` (well, `All` is ok for development).

Causa finita.